# Convert a JSON Object into an SQL table on SQL Server 2019

Tags: json, sql-server-2019

I am trying to convert a JSON object with "keys" as columns and each value in the list as a row.

I have managed to create the table structure I want, however I am getting the wrong number of rows.

```
DECLARE @result NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'{"foo": [101, 202, 303], "bar": [1,2,3], "test": [10,20,30], "input": [100,200,300]}'

SELECT
    foo.value AS foo,
    bar.value AS bar,
    test.value AS test,
    input.value AS input
FROM 
    OPENJSON(@result)
    WITH (
        foo NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.foo' AS JSON,
        bar NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.bar' AS JSON,
        test NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.test' AS JSON,
        input NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.input' AS JSON
    ) AS json
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(foo) AS foo
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(bar) AS bar
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(test) AS test
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(input) AS input
```

This outputs 81 rows of this data:

| foo | bar | test | input |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1 | 10 | 100 |
| 101 | 1 | 10 | 100 |
| 202 | 2 | 20 | 200 |
| 202 | 2 | 20 | 200 |
| 303 | 3 | 30 | 300 |
| 303 | 3 | 30 | 300 |

x 27 rows each for 101 202 and 303 column rows values respectively

I want it to return rows that are length of the values in the list which would be 3 rows in this case:

Expected:

| foo | bar | test | input |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1 | 10 | 100 |
| 202 | 2 | 20 | 200 |
| 303 | 3 | 30 | 300 |

I have tried CROSS APPLY and OUTER APPLY and both give the same output.

Comment: I see. If I change "foo": [101, 202, 303]. I get 27 rows for 101, 27 rows for 202 and 27 rows for 303, (total 81 rows). @Aaron Bertrand

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it without exploding each value by repeating the `CROSS APPLY` against each column. I'm sure other JSON experts can write something less verbose.

```
;WITH src AS
(
  SELECT rn = y.[key], x.[key], y.value
  FROM OPENJSON(@result) AS x
  CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(value) AS y
)
SELECT [foo],[bar],[test],[input] 
FROM
(
  SELECT rn, [key], value = MAX(value) 
  FROM src GROUP BY rn, [key]
) AS d 
  PIVOT (MAX(value) FOR [key] IN 
  ([foo],[bar],[test],[input])) AS p;
```

Results:

| foo | bar | test | input |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1 | 10 | 100 |
| 202 | 2 | 20 | 200 |
| 303 | 3 | 30 | 300 |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fkU-_Jw9)

This adapts easily to any number of values in the array, even non-matching. [Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/hW-ftWiu).

Answer (score 1):

You just need a `WHERE` at the bottom of your query to match the array indexes.

```sql
WHERE foo.[key] = bar.[key]
  AND foo.[key] = test.[key]
  AND foo.[key] = input.[key];
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qNmgiHqR)

Admittedly this only works neatly when all the arrays are the same length.